# Why when I use the ReadAsArray() Shell restart in this code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to read the .pix file in the 3 different  Array in python and I use this program but when I run that  nothing do And shell be restart and program closed .

```
from scipy import ndimage
import os,csv,math,subprocess
from osgeo import gdal
from gdalconst import *
os.chdir(r'"D:\RADARREXAMPLE\outputsac ')  
def importpix (a):
    # open the image
    fn = str(a) + ".pix"
    ds = gdal.Open(fn, GA_ReadOnly)
    print ds
    # get image size
    rows = ds.RasterYSize
    cols = ds.RasterXSize
    band = ds.RasterCount
    # Set NoData Value
    R = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
    G = ds.GetRasterBand(2)
    X = ds.GetRasterBand(3)
    B = ds.GetRasterBand(4)
    c11 = R.ReadAsArray(0, 0, cols, rows)
    c22 = G.ReadAsArray(0, 0, cols, rows)
    c33 = B.ReadAsArray(0, 0, cols, rows)
    c11=pow(c11,2)
    c22=pow(c22,2)
    c33=pow(c33,2)
    # Delete the band and dataset objects
    ds =None
    R = None
    B = None
    X = None
    G = None
    # Write the files to ENVI format
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('ENVI')
    ds = driver.Create('c11.bin', cols, rows, 1, GDT_Float32,['SUFFIX=ADD', 'INTERLEAVE=BSQ'])
    ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(c11, 0, 0)
    ds = None
    ds = driver.Create('c22.bin', cols, rows, 1, GDT_Float32,['SUFFIX=ADD', 'INTERLEAVE=BSQ'])
    ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(c22, 0, 0)
    ds = None
    ds = driver.Create('c33.bin', cols, rows, 1, GDT_Float32,['SUFFIX=ADD', 'INTERLEAVE=BSQ'])
    ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(c33, 0, 0)
    ds = None
    # Write the accompanying config.txt file
    file = open('config.txt', 'w')
    text = "Nrow\n" + str(rows) + "\n ---------\nNcol\n" +str(cols) + "\n ---------\nPolarCase\nmonostatic\n ---------\nPolarType\nfull\n"
    file.write(text)
    file = None
>>> 
>>> importpix ('test11')
<osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0x00000000032A6150> >
13977 7985 4

>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
```